# Python derived enum missing required positional argument

Tags: python, enums

I'm trying to define an object-valued enum, and I'm running in an error of "missing 1 required positional argument" in `enum_member.__init__(*args)`

A basic example of my code, following [the documentation from enum](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#others), let's call it `problem.py` which is imported in `upper.py`

```py
import enum

class test(object):
   def __init__(self, par1, par2):
      # do stuff with the parameters and assign to object fields

   # more object methods

class testlist(test, enum.Enum):
   A = test(1,2)
   B = test(3,4),
   # a few more of these
```

When importing the module in which these classes are defined, I get the following error (edited to match the example):

```
 File "upper.py", line 14, in <module>
    from problem import test
  File "problem.py", line 75, in <module>
    class testlist(test, enum.Enum):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 252, in __new__
    enum_member.__init__(*args)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'par2'
```

I'm guessing that I'm misunderstanding how derived enums work, but from the documentation I can't figure out how I'm missing an argument.

(edit)
The goal is to have `testlist` values behave as `test` objects, which also define a few methods and override arithmetic operators, so I can do e.g., `testlist.A + testlist.B`. The enum isn't strictly necessary, but it's convenient for iteration and groups the values better than having them as global variables in the module.

Comment: Why does `testlist` inherit from `test`? That doesn't make sense

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are allowed to do that to add additional behaviour to your derived enum class. The only restriction is that no base class can define any enumeration values.

Comment: @Kemp that isn't what I'm asking, I'm asking why it does so *in this case*.  It doesn't make sense to have the container inherit from the items it contains

Comment: I believe the issue is that when the Enum is performing its magic at startup it creates an instance of the Enum class for each enumeration value. When it's doing this it doesn't know that it's supposed to be supplying additional arguments to the base class `__init__`, thus the error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was assuming that the minimal example eliminated the context that explained the reason for this way of doing it. The reason for the error occurring doesn't depend on that being explained, though it may mean that the issue can be avoided entirely by changing approach.

Comment: Changing `test`'s init to `def __init__(*args): print(args)` is interesting.

Comment: @Kemp @Juanpa.arrivillaga The goal is to be able to have `testlist` members treated as `test` objects, which also define a few functions and overload arithmetic operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that enum has its own way for `__new__` and `__init__`, in your case, you do not need to have `test` as your parent class. if you do want, follow the documents https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#when-to-use-new-vs-init

without `test` class as your parent class, it will work

```
import enum

class test:
    def __init__(self, par1, par2):
        print(self, par1, par2)

class testlist(enum.Enum):
    A = test(1, 2)
    B = test(3, 4)
```

**EDIT: below code to support + operator**
check the output to understand more how enum subclassing work.

```
import enum

class test(object):
    def __init__(self, par1, par2):
        print(self,':', par1, par2)
        self.par1 = par1
        self.par2 = par2

    def __add__(self, rval):
        print("test:", self, "+", rval)

class testlist(test, enum.Enum):
    A = (1,2)
    B = (3,4)
    # a few more of these
    def __new__(cls, par1, par2):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = test(par1, par2)
        return obj
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(self.__class__, args)


# call __add__ of `testlist` if exist, otherwise __add__ of `test`
testlist.A + testlist.B
# value is `test` object
testlist.A.value + testlist.B.value
```

**output**

```
<__main__.test object at 0x7f112f1d7430> : 1 2
<enum 'testlist'> (1, 2)
<__main__.test object at 0x7f112f1f52e0> : 3 4
<enum 'testlist'> (3, 4)
test: testlist.A + testlist.B
test: <__main__.test object at 0x7f112f1d7430> + <__main__.test object at 0x7f112f1f52e0>
```

Comment: See the edit in the question. Will removing `test` as the parent class allow the behaviour I want (`testlist.A + testlist.B` using the operator in `test.__add__`)?

Comment: update answer for your use case

Answer (score 2):

*Aside*: in your example of `B = test(3,4),` that final comma should not be there.

---

What you are running into is that when you subclass another data type, whatever you assign to the member name will be passed to the subclassed type's `__new__` and/or `__init__`.

In other words, by inheriting from `test`, your `testlist` enum now has an `__init__` that is expecting two arguments: one for `par1` and one for `par2` -- but you are only supplying one argument, e.g. `test(1, 2)`.  What you need to provide is simply `1, 2`:

```
class testlist(test, enum.Enum):
    A = 1, 2
    B = 3, 4
    # a few more of these
```

In the above code the value for `A` will be calculated by calling `test(1, 2)`.

---

Another example that might help: `int` can be called with two arguments, the first being a `str`, and the second a base in which to interpret that string.  So:

```
class Count(IntEnum):
    ONE = 1              # value generated by int(1)
    TWO = '2'            # value generated by int('2')
    THREE = '3', 10      # value generated by int('3', 10)
    TEN = 'A', 16        # value generated by int('A', 16)
```

and when `list`ed:

```
>>> list(Count)
[<Count.ONE: 1>, <Count.TWO: 2>, <Count.THREE: 3>, <Count.TEN: 10>]
```